# Import several json files under different folders

Tags: r

I am new to R and currently trying to make a text analysis of my Facebook messages. I have downloaded the files from Facebook as json files(thanks GDPR!) and they are organised as followed: `Messages_all/inbox/[the persons name followed by a serie of digits, such as JohnSnow_CHg7Bu5MMA]/message.json`

What I want to do is to import all my messages from all my conversations into one file in `R`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
paths <- list.files(mydir, pattern = ".json$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
content <- lapply(paths, jsonlite::fromJSON)
names(content) <- paths
```

should get you started, it uses the `jsonlite` package, `mydir` is the directory where your jsons are downloaded. `content` will be a named list with the contents of the files as elements.

Comment: This worked like a charm, however even though it takes out everything from the json files, it reassembles it into a form I do not really know how to work with. I am more interested in just taking out text strings, and ideally only the text strings of which I am the writer. Do you happen to know how this could be done?

Each message looks like this:
    {
      "sender_name": "Writer's name",
      "timestamp_ms": 1536928480250,
      "content": "Writer's message",
      "type": "Generic"
    },